# How to read big bufferedimage

Tags: java, file, bufferedimage

I am reading a 100 MB picture into my app. It works fine inside Eclipse, but not when I export project to a JAR. Then, I get "Can't read input file!"

Since I need to edit it, I used `BufferedImage`.

```
private String str = "images/1.png";
BufferedImage imageMap;
//in constructor
imageMap = ImageIO.read(new File(str));
```

I have tried this, but the project image does not load inside Eclipse:

```
imageMap = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(str));
```

Comment: Both versions you've tried will, AFAIK, try to read the image out of the JAR file. Where is the image relative to the JAR? Outside? Inside?

Comment: tried loading with image/1.png external, and it worked as for stacktrace none was given when app was starting only nullpointerExeption when image should be shown. Since it worked on from external do i still need images inside jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you working directory if the image is loaded from the file system. Then you see if your relative path `"images/1.png"` is valid. Or you directly check the path of your png

```
System.out.println(new File("."));
File f = new File("images/1.png");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```